# How do I get the number of open file descriptors in UNIX using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unix

I have a command: `ls -la /proc/$$/fd` but I am looking to find a reliable Python snippet of an API call to get the number of open file descriptors in UNIX.

I tried using:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> open_fd = len(psutil.Process().open_files())
>>> print("Open FDs: %d" % open_fd)
Open FDs: 0
```

But it always remained 0 even when I opened a file in another terminal tab using `nano`.

How do I count the total number of open file descriptors using Python?

Comment: you have to use `process ID` in `Process(pid=...)` to get open files for process with this `ID`. For all processes you may need to iterate all processes `for p in psutil.process_iter():
    print(p.open_files())` but it may need root privileges for some processes.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `pid` (`Process ID`) in `Process(pid=...)` to get open files for selecte process.

Something like this

```
import psutil

files = psutil.Process(pid=...).open_files()

print('len(files):', len(files))

for f in files:
    print('FD:', f.fd)
```

---

For all files you may iterate all processes but some processes may need `root` privileges.

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        files = p.open_files() 
        print('len(files):', len(files))
        for f in files:
            print('FD:', f.fd)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('ex:', ex)
```

So you would have to sum all `len()` to get total number.